# Database Post to another Database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

I'm currently a front end developer for a website which lets users sign up and then make purchasing of items.For transactions,  I'm using an API which the payment gateway company provided but when passing data via AJAX certain sensitive data are exposed for the users to see. I was wondering if there is a way that I can pass my parameters to a database (which I'm going to create), and then let the database do the AJAX posting so sensitive parameters can be hidden from the users. Also the database will store the response from the callback.

Comment: a database cant post data, it simply stores it

Comment: is there a way where I can write a php code to do it? like instead of doing it on the front end side (the AJAX)?

Comment: If you dont want expose payment gateway url you can use curl

Comment: @Rishi, well its not just the url I want to hide, there are also certain parameters like say merchant ID or user Key, that are static values in my javascript that I post during an AJAX

Comment: Make the ajax to your own backend and let your server reach out to the remote api. That way everything is hidden from the browser that your clients are using. If the headers are very complex I find using cURL easier. If they are simple then file_get_contents with a stream_context_create is easier. If all the parameters are passed in the url then it's even easier, because you can simply pass it in the url from the backend and not even worry about any special headers at all.

Comment: Normally the server would connect to the payment provider's API, get a transaction id and redirect the user to the payment page with the id. After the payment is done, the user is redirected back to the server which requests the confirmation from the API.

Answer (score 1):

The ajax doesn't have to post to a database unless you want it to, but even then the database would not be what posts the data to a remote api. It's up to your backend php to do that.

Using jquery for the ajax call you would use something like:

```
$.getJSON("your_backend.php", function(result){
   //whatever you want to do with the json returned from the remote site.
}
```

In your_backend.php:

```
<?php
$user = "user name";
$key = "key"
$headers = array(
'http'=>(
    'method'=>'GET',
    'header'=>'Content: type=application/json \r\n'.
        'user:$user \r\n'.
        'key:$key'
    )
)
$context = stream_context_create($headers)

$url_returns = file_get_contents($api_url, false, $context);  

echo $url_returns
?>
```

I haven't debugged this, so it won't work until you go through it, but it should give you an idea about how to proceed. Depending on how complex the connection is with the remote api you may need to use the cURL library for php instead of the file_get_contents.

If you want to save the information in your database you would write an insert statement from the backend php.

Comment: Gotta love those pancakes

Comment: My initial logic was; Front-end passes purchase info to backend. Backend (with static sensitive parameters ; keys, pass, etc. Hidden from users) then Ajax to API. API returns callback to backend. Pass response ("transaction complete") to front end.

Comment: Ajax whether done in raw javascript or jquery happens from the browser. Any communication from a browser to anywhere can be seen. In chrome you can look at network and see all the headers and content sent and received from anywhere. I use it to hack and scrape all day long. I appreciate the positive mark. If you show me how you would ajax the request with dummy data I can write a php script to do the exact same thing.

Comment: @AuntJamaima, So In my front end, do I post an ajax to the php script in the backend so that script can then ajax to the api. Does this also mean that I have to then store the data inside a database so my php can then ajax to the api ? Thanks for the help, really appreciate it, Im new this this backend stuff

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer back sooner. I went to bed. It's not necessesary to save the information in a database unless you want to for some other purpose. Ajax is a browser initiated request. cURL and the file_get_contents are server initiated requests. Show me a sample ajax, with a fake api key and link and I can write the exact request you need and show you what each part does.